# Beautiful soup- trouble removing HTML tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to coding but that will become obvious. I'm trying to extract some text from a webpage.

```
am = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(am.content, 'html.parser')

songs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "songs-list-row__song-name"}, text=True)[0].string
```

There are 4 instances of text that I want to isolate on this web page. This code only outputs one at a time, depending on the number I enter in the [].string bracket. How do I output it as a list, with all four instances?

Thanks.

-I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over your `ResultSet` for example with `list comprehension`:

```
songs = [e.text for e in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "songs-list-row__song-name"}, text=True)]
```

**Note:** *In newer code use `find_all()` instead of old syntax `findAll()`*

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="songs-list-row__song-name">song 1</div>
<div class="songs-list-row__song-name">song 2</div>
<div class="songs-list-row__song-name">song 3</div>
<div class="songs-list-row__song-name">song 4</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

songs = [e.text for e in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "songs-list-row__song-name"}, text=True)]

print(songs)
```

#### Output

```
['song 1', 'song 2', 'song 3', 'song 4']
```